# How to render script tags in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for ways to be able to render a javascript function from a variable in AngularJS. Javascript code below will come from a JSON object and I'd like to render it to the view as HTML. I tried using $sce and ng-bind-html but it generates an error.

```
  <script>
  (function() {
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    var src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
  })();
</script>

<script>
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {

var leaderboardink = googletag.sizeMapping().
addSize([992, 0], [[970, 90], [728, 90], [300, 250], [1, 1]]). //desktop
addSize([768, 0], [[300, 250], [728, 90], [1, 1]]). //tablet
addSize([320, 0], [[320, 50], [320, 100], [300, 250], [1, 1]]). //mobile
addSize([0, 0], [[320, 50], [1, 1]]). //other
build();

    googletag.defineSlot('/61022833/Leaderboard2_INK', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-123456789-0').defineSizeMapping(leaderboardink).addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>

<!-- /61022833/Leaderboard2_INK -->
<div class="gads-contents-1 center">
<div id='div-gpt-ad-123456789-0' style='height:90px; width:728px;'>
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-123456789-0'); });
</script>
</div></div>
```

I tried doing it using $sce but it is failing as it has comments and appends.

Comment: Question is not clear. Please specify your requirement in some words.

Comment: @Nitheesh i edited the requirement.